# How to resolve CS0121 Ambiguous methods or Properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ambiguous

I have a MVC Core Web application. After a failed attempt to add in some session data, where in it asked me to include a missing reference, I suddenly get several Ambiguous reference errors with apparently no way to track pinpoint the offending references.  I have tried to solution clean and rebuild and to restore references but that didn't help.

I do not see a way to find the references on disk ( right clicking on the References in the Solution explorer does not offer options to delete or open location in file explorer.

I DO NOT have the ReSharper tool.

I am at a loss how to fix this error.
Here are my references:

[image]

The specific errors ( 3 of them ) are :

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Source
Error   CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Security.Claims.PrincipalExtensions.FindFirstValue(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal, string)' and 'System.Security.Claims.PrincipalExtensions.FindFirstValue(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal, string)'  OmniPot..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0    C:\zzWork\Omnipot\Main\Source\OmniPot\src\OmniPot\Controllers\AccountController.cs  194 IntelliSense
```

and

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Source
Error   CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)'  OmniPot..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0    C:\zzWork\Omnipot\Main\Source\OmniPot\src\OmniPot\Startup.cs    82  IntelliSense
```

and

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Source
Error   CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure<TOptions>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Action<TOptions>)' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure<TOptions>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Action<TOptions>)'  OmniPot..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0    C:\zzWork\Omnipot\Main\Source\OmniPot\src\OmniPot\Startup.cs    105 IntelliSense
```

Comment: Look at your project.json and make sure they are not referring to different asp.net core versions for libraries you are using.

Comment: I  didn't find a way to debug this type of errors, but the solution that got me working again was very similar to your suggestion Hakunamatata.  I was comparing all my pending changed files against what was in TFS and undoing all changes I didn't explicitly make.  One of the files so reverted was indeed the project.json file.  When I rebuilt after that exercise I was running again.